# Database schema consistency issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, data-modeling

Part of my database schema involves the entities:

```
Jobs
Agencies
Agents
and relation JobAgent
```

- Each Job has one Agency it belongs to
- Each Agent belongs to one agency
- Each Job has 0-n agents

The database will be SQL Server 2008

Here is my schema:

[image]

My problem is that Jobs.agencyid must always be equal to Agents.agencyid when related through JobAgent.
If Jobs.agencyid were to be updated to a new agency, The Agents would then belong to a different Agency than the Job.

What would be the best way to redesign my schema to avoid relying on triggers or application code to ensure this consistency?

Comment: It's unclear to some of us what your issue is - is the primary issue inserting jobs with proper supporting associations, or maintaining the supporting associations?  Because based on the data model provided, there is no insurance that an agent is associated with the agency the job is.

Comment: Both are a concern. When I posted the question I was focusing more on the updates, but ensuring the data is consistent on insert is a requirement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AGENCIES

- agency_id (pk)

### JOBS

- job_id (pk)
- agency_id (fk to AGENCIES.agency_id)

### AGENTS

- agent_id (pk)
- agency_id (fk to AGENCIES.agency_id)

### JOBAGENT

- job_id

  - fk to JOBS.job_id
- agent_id

  - fk to AGENTS.agent_id
- agency_id

  - fk to JOB.agency_id
  - fk to AGENTS.agency_id

You can define more than one foreign key constraint to a column - it just means that the value in JOBAGENT has to satisfy BOTH foreign key constraints to be allowed.  But you'll have fun if you ever want to update jobs to a different agency... ;)  SQL Server supports composite foreign keys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx

### Update Regarding Updating

You have two choices -

- Perform by hand, because `ON UPDATE CASCADE` etc won't handle agency and agent updates without using triggers
- Have a status column in JOB, so you can cancel a job in order to recreate the job with the new supporting records (Agent, jobagent, etc).  Further cleanup can be automated, based on job status if you desire

Comment: Shouldn't the composite-ness of the FK be restricted to JOBS.job_id plus JOBS.agency_id? The OP isn't worried about the Agents moving to a new Agency (though that's potentially also a problem...), so where's the point in FK to AGENTS.agency_id?

Comment: Yes, this will not fix the @OP problem. `UPDATE jobs SET agency_id = whatever` wouldn't be reflected over `agents.agency_id`

Comment: @Anthony Accioly: Which is exactly why the last paragraph of my answer explains that updating will have to be done by hand...

Comment: @Richard Inglis: The AGENT and JOB agency_id needs foreign key constraints to ensure they both match, so an agent for another agency can't be assigned to a job for different agency.  And rather than assume what the OP wants, ***ask them*** before you attempt to impose your assumptions on others.

Comment: Hmm, the more I think about it, the more I prefer your solution to mine, because it enforces the relationship from the start, not just in the case of updates. I also like your JOB.status idea, but for symmetry you might also want an AGENT.status attribute. +1

Comment: Wouldn't I have to create a unique constraint on (jobs.job_id, jobs.agency_id) for this to work as jobs.agency_id is not a PK, or is there another way?

Comment: @CrassHoppr: You could make all three columns in JOBAGENT the primary key because I don't see why you'd attach the same agent more than once to the same job.  Or use a unique constraint - the result is the same, but a primary key would be the perferable option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if a job moves from one agency to another (as you say, if Jobs.agencyid were to be updated...) then the corresponding records in JobAgent become meaningless: those agents *can't* be attached to a job that's no longer with their agency, so the JobAgent records connecting them to the jobs should therefore be deleted...

One way to enforce this is to add a **JobAgent.agencyid** field, and make it a foreign key on **Jobs.agencyid**, with ON UPDATE RESTRICT to force (manual) deletion of the relevant JobAgent records before Jobs.agencyid can be changed.

---

**Edit**: the other issue, which I hadn't really considered, is that when you first associate a job to an agent (ie create a new JobAgent record) you need to ensure they both belong to the same agency... for this, I think [**OMG's solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845398/database-schema-consistency-issue/5845462#5845462) works best - I'm happy to defer to the better answer.

OMG also raises the question of how to handle updates: you can either

1. Change the Jobs.agencyid field and delete (by hand) all associated JobAgent records: in this case the old agents no longer work on this job, and you can assign someone from the new agency to work on it.
2. Change the Jobs.agencyid field and *also change* all associated JobAgent records (ie all those agents move with the job to the new agency) - but this is [very messy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI6JThwcnS4), because those agents will also be associated with other jobs that are still with the original agency.
3. As OMG suggests, make a new Jobs record and mark the old one as defunct (for later deletion).
4. As above but keep the defunct Jobs record to preserve historical information.

Whether you choose 3 or 4 depends a bit on what your system is for: do you just want to maintain the current state of who-has-which-jobs? or do you need to keep some kind of history, for example if there's billing records attached to the job... that info needs to stay associated with the original agency (but this is all outside the scope of your original question).

Comment: +1. You phrased it better than I did lol. Another solution (that would make sense only if its according to the business rules) would be having a foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE between `agents.agencyid` and `jobs.agencyid`this would move every agent linked to the job to the new agency if the job agency gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` with the foreign keys. See this [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). 
Or maybe, if `agencyid` is something that you expect to be mutable, you can have a unique constraint for it and use some other meaningless field for the agency id (say, an auto-increment column).

Comment: That only helps updating, not inserting.

Comment: Guess we interpreted the question differently. If Jobs.agencyid were to be updated to a new agency, The Agents would then belong to a different Agency than the Job. What inserts have to do with the case?

Comment: Getting the inserted records validated via constraints is a higher priority to me - ask the OP.  `ON UPDATE CASCADE` won't run unless *all* the agents for the job now work for the new agency - you're still likely to be updating by hand.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, ok, reading the @OP question I understood that he wants to have Agents.agencyid updated everytime Jobs.agencyid is updated. As I see, there is two alternatives here, using triggers (which the @OP don't want) or having a FK with ON UPDATE CASCADE. With your solution jobs.agency_id and agents.agency_id can still be out of sync (all you need is to update jobs.agency_id). See what I mean?

Comment: What part of "both foreign key constraints have to be satisfied", do you not understand?  That means an agent can't be assigned to a job that is associated with an agency the agent is not associated with.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I understand exactly what It means. The true meaning of the double FK is "there can't be an jobagent.agency_id" without entrances in both jobs.agency_id and agents.agency_id" which will work considering that an entrace on jobagent do exists (ok, looking at the OP answer I belive it will exists in every case). Still, the point is, without ON UPDATE CASCADE or some sort of trigger all you will get is an exception when you try to update jobs.agency_id or agent.agency_id and then, as you pointed out, will have to fire a hell of a lot of statements to make the update manually.

Comment: Still, since @Richard agreed with you and you are both more respected users than me, I consider the case closed. OP will probably just accept your answer and I will just stay the hell away from referencial integrity questions to avoid bashing such as "ON UPDATE has nothing to do with the case" and "What part of ... you do not understand".

Comment: I remember why I stay away from database design questions - sadly, there's not a lot of votes to be had. The OP responded to my comment that both insertion and updating are an issue.  It's not that you don't have a point, but your point is IMO the last 25% of the issue and really doesn't solve anything when it comes to the agents.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following scheme answer your question?

```
    Jobs      Agents     Agencies
      ^          ^          ^
      |          |          |
       \         |         /
        \        |        /
           AgentiatedJob
```

Normally, I have a single-field primary key for every table, because it is easier to match a registry on a table and to refer it on tables below. So following this approach the AgientiatedJob would have at least the fields:

- AgentiatedJobId
- JobId
- AgentId
- AgencyId